# Is there a way to access and work with data stored in GCP bucket directly?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I have to do a deep learning project at my university, where I need to work with a medical image database. This database is stored in a Google Cloud Platform bucket.

However, the database's size is over 4 TB, so I can't afford download the data using `gsutil`. I can't use Google Colab notebook either, since it's disk storage size is 350GB.

Is there any way I can access the data and use it to teach my network?

Comment: In order to access the data in Cloud Storage, your application needs to read it from Cloud Storage or it needs to copy the data to local storage. I would look at the pricing for reading data from Cloud Storage before reading 4,000 GB of data.

Comment: What format is the data on GCS?  You might be able to access the data through BigQuery ... see... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage  How are you going to write your ML application?  Could BigQuery ML satisfy your needs in which case you might not ever need to read the data out of GCS but merely map it to BQ and then have BQ perform your ML modeling.

Comment: @Kolban The data is in `DICOM` format (Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine) format. It also contains `.txt` files for each DICOM file with the corresponding conclusion.
My ML application should do the following: Extract the radiograph images from the DICOM file, input these image into a neural network (which will do the image classification and predict the conclusion).

Comment: Just to be clear, your data isn't one unit of 4TB but is instead a set of objects.   Approximately how many objects and the average size of those objects?

Comment: @Kolban 377,110 DICOM files. Each DICOM file is around 7-15 MBs.

Answer (score 3):

I think you aren't on the right way.

When you build your model, you only need to have a representative subset of your dataset to validate your layers and the expected behavior.

Then, when all is done and packaged, you run your training job on dedicated VM (like Deep Learning VM). This process can be handle automatically by AI-Platform. You can also set up hyper-parameters server and parallelize your training.

In training phase, you often work with batches: you load only a subset of your dataset, you shuffle it and you train perform several steps on this subset (with RMSE/cross-entropy figure out, evaluation, gradient optimization).

Because you use a subset of your full dataset in batches, your don't need to have the 4Tb on your VM at the same time. Your training loop do it for you (download, train, evaluate, delete).

Like I said before, because you use a subset, you can also parallelize your training on several VMs for reducing your training duration.

I recommend you to review your training loop. If your give me the framework name/version which one you work, I could help you with tutorals and examples.

Comment: I have same kind of setup data is stored in google bucket and i am using notebook(under AI platform)/VS code on same platform. Can you please share more tutorials over how can i do parallel training.